# Facing issue in reading the body in Camel REST service

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I am developing 2 camel application :

Camel_1 application is deployable in server_1 and it need to make some rest calls to camel_2 application deployed in server_2.

Camel_1 :

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:/folder/IN")
        .setBody(simple("${null}"))
        .to("http://localhost:9090/camel/my-get-endpoint")
        .log("Service body : ${body['filename']}")
```

Camel_2 :

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
 
        restConfiguration()
           .component("servlet")
           .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
                
        rest()
        .get("/my-get-endpoint")
            .route()
            .outputType(String.class)
            .to("mongodb:camelMongoClient?database=db&collection=myCollection&operation=findAll")
            .log("Body Set ${body}")
            .endRest()
        }
}
```

Camel_2 returns body as :

[Document{{*id=5ef11dd8ee96198e7bf4cb34, configured_email=abc@gmail.com, filename=[A-Z]{4} [A-Z*|a-z_]{1,}*((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))*((0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))_(19|20)\d{2}.(xls[mx]{1}|xls||csv)$}}]

Camel_1 also prints the same body but how do I transform this reponse so that I can pick the required fields and perform methods like ${body.size()}.

Comment: Camel simple language can help with this. https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_ognl_expression_support

Answer (score 0):

You might want to convert the BSON document MongoDB usually returns, into JSON. See if this list helps: [MongoDB type conversions](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mongodb-component.html#_type_conversions).

Answer (score 0):

Converted the body into map and then I was able to access it.